# Web Service is not called by Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services

I`m trying to call to Web Service from ajax and get string array in return,but whatever that i do ,i got 404 error in console log.

This is my client code:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:55397/WebService1.asmx/GetList",
        cache: false, type: "POST", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            tags = data.d;
        },
        error: function () { alert("AutoComplete Server not found");}
    });
```

and this is my Web Service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using ExpressDeal.Models;
using ExpressDeal.Controllers;
using System.Web.Script.Services;


namespace ExpressDeal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 

    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private BaseLogic bl = new BaseLogic();

        [WebMethod]
        [ System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
        //[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public string [] GetList()
        {
            return bl.Context.Items.Select(i=>i.Name).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong with it and how to make it work?

Comment: Start simple.  What happens when you paste the URL `http://localhost:55397/WebService1.asmx/GetList` into a browser bar?

Comment: AFAIK, asmx doesn;t support JSON serialization. It's always going to be SOAP. Seems like you want to use the WebAPI instead of asmx.

Comment: Error:Server Error in '/' Application.

Comment: Of course you can not call your web service like that. Webservice is using SOAP (as default), and you try to call it by POST method?

Comment: You can check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb398995(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to set your method static:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
        //[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public static string [] GetList()
        {
            return bl.Context.Items.Select(i=>i.Name).ToArray();
        }
```